# Проблеммы с url

Tags: php

Вопрос по url, проблема в том что при переходе на сайт с гугла, гугл автоматически добавляет суфикс в конце базового url, пример https://moisite.ru/glavnaya?gclid=CjwKCAjwhqXbAREiwAucoo-1VWr54nvR475D0QB0xrfDQ_UV1wRiNv8WO5HEXb9o4laZeb5xoCHfQQAvD_BwE ,
Проблема в том что нужный мне скрипт подключается только по определенному адресу то есть по этому адресу с суфиксом от гугла он не работает

```
     if ($_SERVER[URL REQUEST] == /glavnaya) {echo "нужный мне скрипт"};
```

Как сдлеать так чтобы скрипт срабатывал и суффиксом от гугла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$re = '/(\/glavnaya)(\?.*|)/';

preg_match($re, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);

if ($matches[1] == '/glavnaya') {
    echo "нужный мне скрипт";
}
```

Например вот так